# Why is my Bash script returning a syntax error?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script which loops into recent files in a folder and executes a command...

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Downloads
recent_files = ($(ls -t | head -20))
for file in "${recent_files[@]}"
do
    ./cmd $file
done
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 3: `recent_files = ($(\ls -t | head -20))'
```

Comment: I suspect you also want `cd $HOME/Downloads`

Comment: I would use `recent_files=($(ls -t | head -20))` instead of `recent_files = ($(ls -t | head -20)) ` no space arround equal.

Comment: 10 upvotes? That is a lot of grateful classmates...

Answer (score 24):

Bash variable assignment scheme is `var=value` i.e. extra spaces are not allowed.

Removing them will correctly assign `ls -t | head -20` output as an array.

So your script should be :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Downloads
recent_files=($(ls -t | head -20))
for file in "${recent_files[@]}"
do
    ./cmd $file
done
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to store the output in a variable at all:

```
cd /home/Downloads
command ls -t | head -20 | while read -r file; do
    ./cmd "$file"
done
```

or even

```
command ls -t | head -20 | xargs -L 1 ./cmd
```

A safer way to work this is with `stat`. It still doesn't protect you from filenames with newlines, but

```
stat -c "%Y %n" * | sort -rn | head -20 | cut -d" " -f2- | xargs -L 1 ./cmd
```

To be foolproof, `find` -- probably need GNU tools for the null-byte handling

```
find . "${find_options[@]}" -printf '%T@ %p\0' | 
sort -zrn |
xargs -0 -L 1 sh -c './cmd "$(echo "$0" | sed "1s/^[0-9.]\\+ //")"'
```

the `find_options` array can be used as a placeholder to add filtering directives, such as

```
find_options=( -type f )
find_options+=( -maxdepth 1 )
find_options+=( -name '*.txt' )
```

and so on

Comment: Since it is generally recommended that the output of `ls` should not be used in scripts, I tried to figure out how to do this with find. I got as far as `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%c\t%f\n' -name '*'`, but the date is still hard to sort. It's not in epoch format yet. The tab is for use later with `cut` after sorting. AFAIK, the answer above (and all the others based on using `ls`) will potentially return directory names as well as file names - which might cause unexpected results with a command which expects to see a regular file.

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the spaces around the equal sign.

```
recent_files=($(ls -t | head -20))
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Removing the outer parentheses would cause `recent_files` to be a scalar rather than an array, which the `${recent_files[@]}` syntax on the next line indicates is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a simpler answer...

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Downloads
for file in $(ls -t | head -20)
do
    ./cmd $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. However, as a help to such problems in the future, you can adopt some practices:

1. Comment out the line that is throwing up an error like so:

```
recent_files=($(ls -t | head -20))
```

and run

```
bash -n myScript.sh
```

This will check errors in the script.

2. Comment out a block of lines like so:

   ```
   : << 'EOF'
   lines
   of
   code
   EOF
   ```

and run

```
bash -n myScript.sh
```

Using this methodology, you will be able to zoom in on the erroneous line in your script.

Coming back to your specific problem, many have already answered what is causing it - the spaces around the `=` sign.